# Adding DateInterval gives one hour off answer in the Azores

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dateinterval

I'm seeing a very strange behavior with `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects, and wanted to know **why** it was behaving this way.

Adding a `DateInterval` of 1 day to a `DateTime` set at midnight results in a `DateTime` set to 1:00 AM ... but only for some dates, and only in some time zones.

```
<?php
$timezone1 = 'Atlantic/Azores';
$timezone2 = 'America/Chicago';

function testZone($tz) {
    printf("*** time zone: %s ***\n", $tz);
    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
    $oneday = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

    $day = new DateTime('2016-03-26 00:00:00');
    printf("Before:\t\t\t%s\n", $day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $day->add($oneday);
    printf("After adding one day:\t%s\n", $day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $day = new DateTime('2016-03-25 00:00:00');
    printf("Before:\t\t\t%s\n", $day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $day->add($oneday);
    printf("After adding one day:\t%s\n", $day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}

testZone($timezone1);
testZone($timezone2);
```

Output:

```
*** time zone: Atlantic/Azores ***
Before:                 2016-03-26 00:00:00
After adding one day:   2016-03-27 01:00:00 <~~ 1 AM!
Before:                 2016-03-25 00:00:00
After adding one day:   2016-03-26 00:00:00
*** time zone: America/Chicago ***
Before:                 2016-03-26 00:00:00
After adding one day:   2016-03-27 00:00:00
Before:                 2016-03-25 00:00:00
After adding one day:   2016-03-26 00:00:00
```

It seems [this has always been a problem in PHP](https://3v4l.org/AJKtp).

It doesn't make any sense to me. When adding whole date intervals to whole dates, why would there ever be an extra hour added?

I know I can work around it, but is there some setting I can tweak to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because Portuguese *summer time*  starts exactly on `2016-03-27`.

If you understand Portuguese, you can read:

http://oal.ul.pt/hora-legal/mudanca-da-hora/

> Região Autónoma dos Açores
>
> Em conformidade com a legislação, a hora legal na Região Autónoma dos
>   Açores:
>
> será adiantada  60 minutos às 0 horas de tempo legal (1 hora UTC) do dia 27 de Março e atrasada  60 minutos à 1 hora de tempo legal (1 hora UTC) do dia 30 de Outubro.

Comment: If this is the case, then why does it [not give an extra hour when rolling over Daylight Savings (2017-03-12 02:00:00) within a USA time zone](https://3v4l.org/vaer1)?